# Mapping hash of integer and array of objects to other format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have this format of my hash, which I obtain from my db using this `Entity.where('source_id is not null').select([:system_id, :source_id, :name]).group_by(&:system_id)`:

```
{6=>
  [#<Obj name: "Lease", system_id: 6, source_id: "369">,
   #<Obj name: "Docks", system_id: 6, source_id: "864">,
   #<Obj name: "Marinas", system_id: 6, source_id: "1630">,
   #<Obj name: "Transporters", system_id: 6, source_id: "229">,
   #<Obj name: "Stations", system_id: 6, source_id: "83258">,
   #<Obj name: "Stations", system_id: 6, source_id: "2407">,
  ]}
```

I want to have this as a end result :

```
{6=> 
  {"369" => "Lease", "864" => "Docks", "1630" => "Marinas", "229" => "Transporters", "83258" => "Stations", "2407" => "Stations"} 
}
```

Or :

```
{6=> 
  {"369" => #<Obj name: "Lease", system_id: 6, source_id: "369">, "864" => #<Obj name: "Docks", system_id: 6, source_id: "864">, "1630" => #<Obj name: "Marinas", system_id: 6, source_id: "1630">, "229" => #<Obj name: "Transporters", system_id: 6, source_id: "229">, "83258" => #<Obj name: "Stations", system_id: 6, source_id: "83258">, "2407" => #<Obj name: "Stations", system_id: 6, source_id: "2407">} 
}
```

Which ever is easier to produce. I basically want to replace the array of objects with hash that has keys source_id and values either obj name or the entire object.

I've tried :

```
.each{|c_id, c| new_format = {c_id => {c.source_id => c} } }
NoMethodError: undefined method `source_id' for #<Array:0xb4bc4e4>
```

and

```
.each{|c_id, c| new_format = {c_id => c.group_by(&:source_id) } }
NameError: undefined local variable or method `new_format' for main:Object
```

And couple of other options but I didn't manage to produce the correct result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 # records is the hash returned by dbquery
 records.map{|k,v| records[k] = v.inject({}) {|hsh,obj| hsh[obj.source_id] = obj.name;hsh } }
```

This would modify the `records` hash to your desired format.

Comment: Nice use of map here.

Comment: @tihom this maps the inner map well i.e `{"369" => "Lease", "864" => "Docks", "1630" => "Marinas", "229" => "Transporters", "83258" => "Stations", "2407" => "Stations"}` but I'm missing `6 =>` parent key

Comment: this call would modify the records hash itselt. `records = { 6 => {"369" => "Lease", "864" => "Docks"...}, ...}`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
top_hash.each { |key, array|
  top_hash[key] = array.each_with_object({}) { |obj, hash|
    hash[obj.source_id] = obj.name
  }
}
```